# Вывод данных при выборе значения из выпадающего списка

Tags: php, html, mysql

Есть выпадающий список находящийся в ячейке таблицы с ФИО сотрудников, как сделать чтобы в определенные ячейки вывелись все остальные поля соответствующего сотрудника из таблицы `Сотрудников`

```
<tr>  
<td>
<select name="employees">
<option value="" >Выберите сотрудника</option>
<?PHP         
$res = mysql_query('select id, имя, фамилия, отчество from `employees`');
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
?>
<option value="<?=$row['id']?>"><?=$row['имя'] ?>&nbsp<?=$row['фамилия']?>&nbsp<?=$row['отчество']?></option>
<?
}
?>
</td> 
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

И так, поскольку Вы уточнили Ваше условие, постараюсь улучшить свой ответ. Вы уже привели в вопросе код, для заполнения `select` всеми ФИО сотрудников. Далее, если нужно обновить страницу, мы можем рассмотреть два варианта:

**Первый вариант:** Повесить событие `onchange` на изменение `select`. В этом событии, мы получаем `value` (Вы указали там `id`), и по этому `id` формируем `AJAX` запрос к какому-то php-скрипту, передав ему через `GET` или `POST` нужный `id`, который будет загружать остальные данные, и возвращать их, например, через разделитель. Получив данные, применяем `split` по символу-разделителю, и выводим полученные данные в соответствующее (оставшиеся) поля таблицы.

**Плюс этого способа:** динамичность - любое изменение сразу формирует обновление таблицы.

**Минус:** JS может быть отключен в настройках браузера.

Исходя из этого, можно применить дублирующий метод, или, если не нужна автоматическая загрузка данных, то можно использовать **второй вариант:**

Итак, есть `select`, у которого выбран какой-то пункт, добавив под ним кнопку `submit`, и разместив эти элементы внутри формы. Можно указать `action` формы эту же страницу, метод передачи, можно выбирать `POST` для скрытия данных от их отображения в адресе, или же наоборот, `GET` - то указывать их в адресе страницы, тогда зная `id`, можно будет сразу найти нужного сотрудника, не выбирая его в списке. Итак, внутри страницы, в зависимости от того, какой метод передачи был выбран, нужно проверить, заполнен ли массив (`_POST` или `_GET`), и если в нем есть данные, то в `select` указать запрашиваемый `id`, а так же сформировать по этому `id` второй запрос, для получения оставшихся данных, и вывести их, посредством `php`.

---

А какова полная структура данных таблицы `Сотрудников`?

По логике вопроса, нужно делать запрос:

```
SELECT * from `employees`
```

Вы получите ассоциативный массив, и в `input` первой ячейки выводите ФИО, как Вы указали, далее, если количество оставшихся полей известно, то просто выводите их, иначе, получаете количество полей из запроса, отнимаете 4 (учитывая, что Вам не нужно уже обрабатывать ФИО и `id`), и через цикл добавляете новые ячейки таблицы (например, через `echo`), а в них уже заполняете оставшиеся поля таблицы, полученные из запроса.

**P. S.** Это все, при условии, что я правильно понял объяснение Вашего вопроса.

Comment: допустим есть поле Должность и у каждого сотрудника своя должность,мне нужно вывести должность сотрудника выбраного в выпадающем списке

Comment: Если я правильно Вас понял, то после того, как Вы вывели все ФИО сотрудников в `input`, и выбрали в этом `input` нужного сотрудника, Вам нужно получить в оставшихся ячейках, все данные о нем, типа должность и т. д.?

Comment: Если это так, то Вам нужно вначале сформировать `input` (код, который Вы указали в вопросе), а потом, либо через AJAX, либо через форму по выбранному значению `input` обновить таблицу, указав в ней оставшиеся поля для выбранного сотрудника.